# Figuring out all functions parameter pattern matches

Tags: agda

Having:

```
data Bin : Set where
  nil : Bin
  x0_ : Bin → Bin
  x1_ : Bin → Bin

data One : Bin → Set where
  one : One (x1 nil)
  y0_ : ∀ {bin : Bin} → One bin → One (x0 bin)
  y1_ : ∀ {bin : Bin} → One bin → One (x1 bin)

one-ident : ∀ {x : Bin} → One x → to (from x) ≡ x
```

What is the logic that generates all the functions parameter pattern matches?

```
one-ident one = {!   !}
one-ident {x0 x} (y0 o) = {!   !}
one-ident {x1 x} (y1 o) = {!   !}
```

For example knowing the first argument is `{x0 x}` why does the 2nd argument have to be `(y0 o)`? Why can't 2nd argument be `(y1 o)`?

The code example was taken from [here](https://github.com/zgrannan/plfa.github.io/blob/solutions/src/plfa/Relations.lagda#L927-L941).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
one-ident : ∀ {x : Bin} → One x → to (from x) ≡ x
one-ident one = {!   !}
one-ident {x0 xx} (y0 o) = {!   !}
one-ident {x1 xx} (y1 o) = {!   !}
```

When you know that `x` is `x0 xx` in one-ident you know that the type of the second argument is `One (x0 xx)`. There is only 1 constructor in `One` that can have that type, namely `y0_`.